# Get minimum and maximum decimal scale value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have float datatype column in sql server and I need to get minimum decimal scale and maximum decimal scale .

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a93ba/2)
 I am using

```
Len (Cast(Cast(Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), value, 128)
                     ) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
```

Which work great but when value is something in negative eg `-0.061` it throw error `Error converting data type varchar to float.`
So for alter I search and found that there is function name `PARSENAME(@var,1)` which is working perfect for negative numbers too but this function returns after decimal value and return type is `nchar`

Eg : If float value is -0.061 its will return 061 of return type `nchar` So i can not use `len` function to get its length.

SO how do I make this working either by using fiddle or by using above function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `ABS()` function

```
SELECT value,
       Decimals = CASE Charindex('.', value)
                    WHEN 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE
   Len (Cast(Cast(Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ABS(value), 128)
                     ) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
                  END
FROM   numbers
```

Comment: There is possibility of  `Arithmetic overflow error while converting float value to data type bigint`  if the maximum scale value exceeds 20.  so use `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(value, 'Scale')`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using [ABS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function should be enough. Shouldn't it?

> A mathematical function that returns the absolute (positive) value of
>   the specified numeric expression.

```
SELECT value
    , Decimals = CASE CHARINDEX('.', value)
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        ELSE LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ABS(value), 128)) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
    END
FROM numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work. 
Just replace simple value with -value when it is negative i.e 
CASE WHEN value<0 THEN -value ELSE value END

```
   SELECT value,
          Decimals = CASE WHEN Charindex('.', value)=0
                          THEN 0
                          ELSE Len (Cast(Cast(Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ABS(value), 128) ) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
                     END
   FROM   numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove - symbol, use ABS function. ABS(value) in place of value